# Rebuild in-memory Lucene index for existing Fuseki TDB store

Tags: fuseki

I'm trying to setup a Fuseki service with a persistent TDB store and an in-memory Lucene index. [My configuration](https://gist.github.com/danmichaelo/9edc44d5fbf1defc10ab) works fine. But when I restart Fuseki, the in-memory index is of course lost. Is there any way to rebuild the index without having to reload the data? I know I can use

```
$ java -cp $FUSEKI_HOME/fuseki-server.jar jena.textindexer --desc=config.ttl
```

if I had a persistent index, but since it requires Fuseki to be stopped, it doesn't work with an in-memory index.